# how to add a DateTimeOffset to a DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a problem, i have a `DateTimeOffset` and a `DateTime`, and i want to know how to add the Offset to the DateTime?

DateTimeOffset e.g. is +02:00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx
says that DateTimeOffset already contains both a DateTime and an offset.

You probably want to use a TimeSpan instead of a DateTimeOffset. TimeSpan's can be added to DateTimes.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, DateTimeOffset is not what a normal person would understand from it's name. Simply put it's a DateTime WITH an offset (maybe not exactly just this; but close enough). Imo this is the worst named class in the whole .NET. The name came straight from SQL Server afaik. You can refer to this for details:

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/23/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset-in-net/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you need to add +2:00 to a `DateTime`. You can do,

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2.0);
```

Comment: ok, I realized that I downvoted it wrongly. Can u edit it so that I can modify my vote?

fyi: I had issues when subtracting a date from the system minimum date, which won´t happen here.

Answer (score 4):

The [`DateTimeOffset` class](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/23/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset-in-net/) "represents a point in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day, relative to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)." It contains both a `DateTime` value and an offset, so if you want to add the offset to the `DateTime`, you would want to create a new `DateTimeOffset` using the constructor, and then use one of the `AddX()` functions for `DateTimeOffset` to modify the offset value.

```
var offset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

See [this blog post](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/23/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset-in-net/) for examples on how to convert from one to the other, perform arithmetic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by passing in the relevant values to `AddMinutes` or `AddHours` of your `DateTime` instance

`startDate.AddHours(2)` will increment the current DateTime object by 2 hours (*to decrement it would be -2*)

Or you can intialize a Timespan object like

`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(2,0,0);`

Now you can add this to your DateTime object

```
startDate= startDate+ ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to make an offset-less time having an offset (e.g. +02:00) is
assuming that timeZone is e.g. 04:00
and utc is a DateTimeOffset structure, initialized on GMT.

```
var timeZone = TimeZone.FromSeconds(14400)
var localTime= utc.ToOffset(timeZone)
```